# How to connect YMSG (Yahoo IM service) by server IP

Tags: chat, instant-messaging, yahoo-messenger, pidgin

I need a IM client that support yahoo and allow user to set yahoo IM server address.

Yahoo IM servers names (scs.msg.yahoo.com, scsa.msg.yahoo.com, scsb.msg.yahoo.com, scsc.msg.yahoo.com) are not accesible through my company LAN, so I should use IP addresses of their servers.

Answer (score 0):

We can find ip of a domain name by simply pinging that domain name.
My problem was related to another network issue (port 443 was blocked) but initially I supposed that it relates to server ip address.